# Debugging Question - VS 2008 web services on Cassini

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, debugging, cassini

I'm testing a web service in Visual Studio, and stepping through using the debugger.

Then I click stop debugging. This stops the debugging session, but the program continues to run like a runaway train.

Is this a "bug" or a "feature" of Visual Studio 2008? If it's a feature, how can I tell Visual Studio to halt execution when I click on 'stop debugging'?

Comment: All your answers are equally as useful, but I can only select one as the correct answer. thank you for your answers though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server that visual studio uses will keep running in the background. You  should be able to stop it using the icon in the task bar.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you have lots of instances running, my favourite little trick is to pop open the run command and type:

> tskill webdev

Answer (score 1):

When you run webservices, even when you stop them, they still run on the background, what you can do is look in the taskbar on the  right hand side and close out the instances of the webservice that are running by right clicking on the icon and pressing stop.

Answer (score 1):

While you've stopped debugging the application chances are that the asp.net developement server is running. you should be able to stop that from its tray icon